# Visual Basic find the latest letter (in alphabetic order) with recursion

Tags: vb.net, recursion

I have been stuck for days trying to figure out how to do this. What I want to do is to find the latest letter in a string by using recursion, where A is the earliest and Z is the latest.

I know recursion is not the best way to do this, but it's a part of the task I have been given, so I hope someone can help me.

```
Private Function størstTegn(s As String) As String
        Dim j As Integer

        If s = "" Or s Is Nothing Then
            Return s
        Else
            Dim lengde As Integer = s.Length

            For i As Integer = 0 To lengde - 1
                If s(i) < s(j + i) Then
                    s.Remove(i)
                End If
            Next i
            Return s(0)
        End If
    End Function
```

Comment: You could have a dictionary with 26 entries, each letter has a numeric value. check which is the highest. I won't do it for you, but there's an idea to work with.

Comment: I have tried many things, the code I just posted now is my current one...

Comment: latest letter means want? post example string and output

Comment: Your current method doesn't use recursion.  You really don't need recursion.  Just loop through the characters of the string and keep track of the highest one.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is iterative, not recursive.

```
Private Function GetMaxCharacter(ByVal ToEvaluate As String, CurrentMaxChar As String) As String
    If ToEvaluate.Length > 0 Then
        If ToEvaluate.Substring(0, 1) > CurrentMaxChar Then
            CurrentMaxChar = ToEvaluate.Substring(0, 1)
        End If
        ToEvaluate = ToEvaluate.Substring(1, ToEvaluate.Length - 1)

        CurrentMaxChar = GetMaxCharacter(ToEvaluate, CurrentMaxChar)
    End If

    Return CurrentMaxChar
End Function
```

Comment: The function gets the character "?" as max character.

Comment: Call as such "GetMaxCharacter("abczdef","")". I'm not filtering characters as that was not part of the request. He wanted a recursive approach to find the highest letter in the alphabet. I'm not taking case into account or other characters.

Answer (score 0):

> UPDATED to avoid special characters such as ¿,?,ñ,ç

...Or you can do it using `LINQ`:

```
    Dim str As String = "qwerty012345"

    Dim BiggestLetter As Char = GetBiggestLetter(str)

    MessageBox.Show(CStr(BiggestLetter))

Private Function GetBiggestLetter(ByVal str As String) As Char

    Return (From c As Char In str.ToLower
            Where "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".Contains(c)
            Order By c Descending).FirstOrDefault

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has some issues.

You aren't using the variable `j`, so `i + j` is always equal to just `i`, so nothing ever gets removed from the list.  It always returns the value of the first character in the string.

The bigger problem is that you are *trying* to remove items from the list you are iterating over.  That will mess up the character indexes you are iterating over.  That can be done if you go in reverse order, but isn't necessary.

This isn't a recursive problem, and since your attempted solution wasn't using recursion either, I suspect a misunderstanding on your part about what recursion is.

A simple iteration that checks the highest character value is all that is needed:

```
Private Function størstTegn(s As String) As String
  Dim maxChar As Char
  For i As Integer = 0 To s.Length - 1
    If Char.IsLetter(s(i)) AndAlso s(i) > maxChar Then
      maxChar = s(i)
    End If
  Next
  Return maxChar.ToString
End Function
```